# How can I integrate the stylesheet on database using roots?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

How can I integrate the stylesheet on database using 'roots.io'?

to use and edit it direct from wordpress admin.

It's because my main stylesheets are not the styles.css, but instead of I use assets/css/app.css, so how can I integrate it to be edited on admin?

Answer (score 1):

You Can set your your new stylesheets at same path for styles.css.
Its work for me. If i set new stylesheet at another path i can't edit it form wordpress admin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but maybe it could have another solution.

Comment: Do you use roots.io ?